# How do i set a proxy url for Artillery load test?

Tags: load-testing, artillery

We have to use a proxy server to send requests to our API for security purposes. it is in the http `//<ip-address>:<port>` format.

How do I add this proxy server in my ArtilleryJS yml file so that requests are sent using this proxy?

there is a mention of of using the HTTP_PROXY environment variable to pass it, but there is a lack of clear documentation in this regard.

Has someone tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work, one year later by setting the global variable HTTP_Proxy in right in my call to artillery in the terminal by adding this to my package.json

"artillery": "HTTP_PROXY='http://192.168.1.25:8080/' DEBUG=http,http:response artillery run -o 'report.json'"